# Getting [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error while starting with PyTerrier

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

This is all the code that I wrote:

`import pyterrier as pt`

`if not pt.started(): pt.init()`

And the full error is:
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

Tried looking up solutions but found no clear explanation

Evidently doing something fundamentally wrong. Any advice?

Comment: What URL are you trying to call? That URL probably has a self-signed certificate that isn't trusted.

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have resolved it:

`import ssl`

`ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`

Comment: Perhaps, by eliminating security.

Comment: Fair point. But this is for a small-ish university project so I don't mind that much